# Trouble saving and displaying intent data

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I wanted to save the title of a cardview whenever it is clicked. I'm pretty sure I'm sending the text title in a correct manner but for some reason, I couldn't save the text whenever an item is clicked. BTW, Whenever the item is clicked, it opens my another activity called "favorite" and it shows the text that I want, but whenever I open it manually, it shows nothing. Please refer this image as a reference.

Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thanks.

Before clicking

[image: Before clicking]

After clicking

[image: after clicking]

Here's my RecyclerAdapter. I tried sending data in two ways, intent and SharedPreferences but both didn't work

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>{

 Context context;
 ArrayList<Album> albums;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Album> albums){
    this.context=c;
    this.albums=albums;
}
// Initialize holder
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

   View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model,null);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
   return holder;
}

//Bind data to views
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

  holder.nameTxt.setText(albums.get(position).getName());
  holder.img.setImageResource(albums.get(position).getImage());

 //listener
    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {



            Toast.makeText(context,albums.get(pos).getName() + " ,added to favorite ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // sending data using intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, favorite.class);
            intent.putExtra("text", albums.get(pos).getName());
            intent.putExtra("t", albums.get(pos).getImage());
            context.startActivity(intent);



            // data sharing using sharedPref
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("lado", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("mug",albums.get(pos).getName());
            editor.apply();


        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return albums.size();
}
}
```

And this is my another activity and I would like to save and display the text.

```
public class favorite extends AppCompatActivity {

 @BindView(R.id.demoText)
 TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    /**
     * I'm using bundle here
     */

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null){
        String value2 = bundle.getString("text");
        tv.setText(value2);
    }
    /**
    *  I'm using sharedPref here
    */

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("lado", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        String name = prefs.getString("mug", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
        tv.setText(name);
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're launching the favorite activity first and then saving the data in `SharedPreferences`.

Try to save the value first in `SharedPreferences` and then launch the activity and try to get the value in next activity, you will get.

Edited :

holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {

```
        Toast.makeText(context,albums.get(pos).getName() + " ,added to favorite ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // data sharing using sharedPref
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("lado", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("mug",albums.get(pos).getName());
        editor.apply();

        // sending data using intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, favorite.class);
        intent.putExtra("text", albums.get(pos).getName());
        intent.putExtra("t", albums.get(pos).getImage());
        context.startActivity(intent);


    }
});
```

and in the favorite activity you should get `"mug"` not `"text"` because you didnt set "text" in first activty

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("lado", MODE_PRIVATE);
    //String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    //if (restoredText != null) {
        String name = prefs.getString("mug", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
        tv.setText(name);
  //  }
```

Comment: I think I just followed what you just said, didn't work. Could you please post the pseudocode? thanks

Comment: Thanks got it. just curious, can I do the same thing using intent only?

Comment: yes, you can do it in intent only. but if you need this selection for later usage you can use share preference